# Can I create new service in google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, deployment

my service name : GGD

app_GGD.yaml

```
runtime: python38
service: GGD
instance_class: F2
...
```

command : gcloud app deploy --appyaml=app_GGD.yaml

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) An error occurred while parsing file: [app_GGD.yaml]
Unable to assign value 'GGD' to attribute 'service':
Value 'GGD' for service does not match expression '^(?:^(?!-)[a-z\d\-]{0,62}[a-z\d]$)$'
  in "app_GGD.yaml", line 3, column 10
```

Is there anything else I need to set up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The App Engine service name use lower case letters, numbers and dashes (hypens). The service name must begin and end with a lower case letter.

The error message contains the regular expression `^(?:^(?!-)[a-z\d\-]{0,62}[a-z\d]$)$`. This expression defines the character set and format of a service name.